# How to select multiple rows from a (geo)pandas dataframe based on an array or propagate metadata of a clustering algorithm result?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, cluster-analysis, geopandas

I have a geopandas data frame that contains a polygon, region_id and center_point lat and lon in Radians that looks like this:

[image]

I then wanted to go about clustering each region by their center point and did the following:

```
#Set Up
kms_per_radian = 6371.0088
eps = 0.1/kms_per_radian
coords = blocks_meta.as_matrix(columns=['lat', 'lon'])

#Cluster
from sklearn.cluster import DBSCAN

db = DBSCAN(eps=epsilon, algorithm='ball_tree', metric='haversine', min_samples=1).fit(coords)
labels = db.labels_
clusters = pd.Series([coords[labels == n] for n in range(len(set(labels)))])
```

which yields an array of clusters of center points that looks like this.

```
array([[ 0.0703843 ,  0.170845  ],
       [ 0.07037922,  0.17084981],
       [ 0.07036705,  0.17085678],
       [ 0.0703715 ,  0.17083775]])
```

What I am struggling to figure out how to do is to get the regions_ids associated with each cluster to merge the polygons to create one bigger region without looping through each cluster and for each lat,lon pair and querying the dataframe.

Is there a way of propagating the ids or querying the dataframe per cluster?

Any help here would be appreciated.

Thanks!

**EDIT**

What I want to avoid is doing this:

```
clusters_of_regions = []

for cluster in clusters:
    cluster_of_regions_ids = []
    for entry in cluster:
        print(cluster[0][0])
        region_id = blocks_meta.loc[blocks_meta['lat'] == cluster[0][0]]['region_id'][1]
        cluster_of_regions_ids.append(region_id)
    clusters_of_regions.append(cluster_of_regions_ids)
```

Both to avoid the nested for loop - and when ever I try I keep on getting a key error:

Is there a way I cluster on the regions themselves using the center points as properties.

Thanks

Comment: you can loop over groups of identical region_ids with pandas DataFrama `groupby` like: `gdf.groupby('region_id')`

Comment: @API, I don't have the "groups" of region_ids. This is the problem.
Each region is unique. When I cluster it - I no longer have the region Ids - only the center points. I need a way to go from the cluster to region id, without looping creating a nested loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the example from skleanr (https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.DBSCAN.html). I modified it here to have a dataframe and resemble your example.

```
from sklearn.cluster import DBSCAN 
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np 

X = np.array([[1, 2], [2, 2], [2, 3], [8, 7], [8, 8], [25, 80]])

df = pd.DataFrame(X, index=list(range(len(X))), columns = ['col1', 'col2'])

clustering = DBSCAN(eps = 3, min_samples = 2).fit(df) 
labels = clustering.labels_ 

df = df.merge(pd.Series(labels).to_frame().rename(columns={0:'clusters'}), left_index = True, right_index = True, how = 'outer')

df
```

Gives you:

```
        col1    col2    clusters
     0  1        2       0
     1  2        2       0
     2  2        3       0
     3  8        7       1
     4  8        8       1
    5   25      80      -1
```

According to the description:

> labels_ : array, shape = [n_samples] Cluster labels for each point in
>   the dataset given to fit(). Noisy samples are given the label -1.

In the example, you get two groups (labels 0 and 1). The -1 is a 'noisy' sample, here that sample is clearly larger than the others.

If you do something similar to this you can have your regions_id and the label next to each other and compare whether there is a 1:1 relation or not.

Answer (score 0):

I think your groups are in your labels. 
I think what you want is this (I am using `labels = [1,2,3,4]`):

`df1 = pd.DataFrame(ar) 
df1.loc[:,'labels'] = pd.Series(labels) 
df1`

That will create a df like this one :

```
    0   1   labels
0   0.070384    0.170845    1
1   0.070379    0.170850    2
2   0.070367    0.170857    3
3   0.070372    0.170838    4
```

Comment: Hey @Jorge! The region ids are never passed as labels to the fit function - so this wont work. See edit for clarification

Comment: @JohnyMudy, the clustering algorithm is going to cluster your 'rows' (aka data points) by 'similarities' among them not by regions. It is likely that each 'region,' as per your df is split or join with other regions, therefore, you will not get the same regions. In other words, your determined clusters very likely do not correspond to your id_regions. In your labels variable, you hae a list of identifiers for each cluster, likely [0,1,2,3], these are the 'cluster' ids - not regions

Comment: Thank you. So what you are saying is the actual data points returned by the clustering will return modified versions of the datapoints? There is a one to one relationship between the region id and the point - and given that the clustering algorithm is clustering the points - I should beable to get reference each point in the cluster to an ID - which is what tripping me up. When using the for loop I seem to be getting a key value error. DBScan should not modify the points in the cluster themselves - is this just an sklearns implementation?

Comment: @JohnyMudly check my new answer below